# Что должен знать разработчик компьютерных игр? (Unity + UE4 + серверная часть)

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Для себя лично определился, что хочу заниматься созданием игр/обучающих симуляторов, используя такие среды как Unity, Unreal Engine 4.

Сайты, разработка ПО с нуля, обычные бизнес App(для мобилок/планшетов) - не моё. Не лежит душа к этому.

Такой вопрос: что должен знать сегодня "разработчик компьютерных игр "(Unity + UE4), чтобы действительно считаться профи, а не быть джуниуром на подхвате?
Очень много материала, очень много фреймворков для изучения. Потерялся.

Нужно ли мне знать WCF? WPF? WinForms? Нужен ли мне вообще как таковой JS? Или ASP.net с SQL покроет все нужды современной серверной части со стороны именно "разработчика игр"?

На данный момент знаю:

- 3D моделинг (HighPoly/LowPoly),.
- Текстуринг, сетап персов, анимации (суммарно опыта лет 9).
- C# (Unity Developer).

Так же работал с технологиями AR, VR (есть законченные коммерческие проекты).

Владею HLSL (программирование шейдеров).

Знаю как создавать клиент-серверное взаимодействие, используя Photon Server.

Но на собеседованиях то и дело сталкиваюсь с разными реализациями "собственных" серверов, требованиями писать собственные плагины для Unity. (Не кастомные Inspector Editor для левл-дизайнеров, а прям плагины dll, например под ту же технологию Arduino).

Тут я вообще в ауте, даже не представляю что для этого нужно знать из фреймворков. Как люди пишут такие чудеса.

Подскажите пожалуйста ещё, что по серверной части должен знать "разработчик компьютерных игр"? Я так понял, что Photon-server - это вообще "дно". Каждая компания хочет свой сервер с нуля.

Что в этом плане изучать? UDP, IP, Node.js? Не понимаю в каком направлении двигаться...

Answer (score 4):

Вообще у вас слишком много всего в вопросе, хорошо бы его разбить на несколько отдельных вопросов. Но постараюсь ответить.

> что должен знать сегодня "разработчик компьютерных игр "(Unity + UE4),
>   чтобы действительно считаться профи, а не быть джуниуром на подхвате?

Если разработчик может сам поставить задачи, декомпозировать их, назначить правильные ETA и реализовать эти задача плюс-минус в эти сроки, то он профи.

> Нужно ли мне знать WCF? WPF? WinForms?

Для работы в Unity/UE - нет.

> Нужен ли мне вообще как таковой JS?

Не понимаю, при чём тут вообще js...В Unity пишут на [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), а в Unrreal на [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

> Или ASP.net с SQL покроет все нужды современной серверной части со
>   стороны именно "разработчика игр"?

На ASP.net никто сервак для игр не делает. Про SQL же...не факт, что вам нужна именно реляционная СУБД, возможно лучше подойдёт документоориентированная.

> требованиями писать собственные плагины для Unity

Если вы создаёте игру под Android, то знание Android очень пригодится. В принципе, без этих знаний вы плагин и не напишете вовсе. Но бежать изучать только ради написания плагина не стоит, зря время потеряете. В команде обычно эти занимается тот, кто в этом шарит, а вам лучше прокачивать ваши ключевые компетенции.

> Подскажите пожалуйста ещё, что по серверной части должен знать
>   "разработчик компьютерных игр"? Я так понял, что Photon-server - это
>   вообще "дно". Каждая компания хочет свой сервер с нуля.

Я бы рекомендовал вам определиться, вы хотите работать с клиентом (unity/ue) или с бекендом (node.js/java и т.п.). Это абсолютно разные области. Вы не сможете стать профи и там, и там.

Photon-server в 2019 уже довольно неплох, но всё зависит от типа/жанра вашей игры.

> Что в этом плане изучать? UDP, IP, Node.js? Не понимаю в каком
>   направлении двигаться...

UDP, IP, HTTP, TCP - это общая базовая теория. Это желательно знать всем, независимо от специализации.

Почему вы именно про [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) спрашиваете? Нода для написания API хороша, но как полноценный бекенд, скажем, для игры с синхронным мультиплейером, совсем не годится.

Comment: А чем плох api на asp’е для игр если в двух словах?

Comment: @yolosora про ASP.NET Core не скажу, но старый ASP был медленным, глючным и хреновым в плане разработки. Для апишечки пойдёт, как сервак для мультиплейерной игры - нет.